# Using ACF field in do_shortcode()

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I have a shordcode for Contact Form 7 form. I want use Advanced Custom Fields for ID value. How Can I do that?

the ACF with ID value:

```
the_field('form');
```

shordcode:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="29"]' ); ?>
```

Any solution? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="'.get_field('form').'"]' ); ?>
```

You have to notice, you should use `get_field()` to return the value. `the_field()` will echo it.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! I've done that before but I miss the ' '. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're most welcome :) enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

Copy your shortcode in your WordPress text field:

`[contact-form-7 id="29"]`

And:

```php
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_field('form')); ?>
```

Very small difference, a little bit easier.